# How to make a function to call some method right after the end of the curly brace in coffee script?

Tags: coffeescript

js code:

```
function() {
    alert(1);
}.bind(this);
```

How to write this code in coffee script version?
I tried:

```
->
    alert 1
.bind this
```

But it reported an error: unexpected .
I also tried:

```
(->
    alert 1
).bind this
```

But the compiled js code is not what I want:

```
(function() {
    (function() {
        return alert(1);
    }).bind(this);

}).call(this);
```

How to solve this issue? Thanks a lot

Comment: The outer `(function() { ... }).call(this);` is the [scoping wrapper](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope) that CoffeeScript puts around everything (unless you compile with `-b`) so ignore that. That leaves you with exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Function chaining has a long history on coffeescript...
See https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/1495

In your case, when doing the `bind`, maybe use the coffeescript fat arrow instead... so your function becomes this:

```
=>
    alert 1
```

Which will bind the function to the current context.

In any other case, function chaining can be done using a syntax like this

```
foo.test()
.next()
.last()
```

Which will compile to

```
foo.test().next().last();
```

As far as I know, is chaining using only an anonymous function syntactically not possible.

Comment: `(-> ...).bind this` works just fine and produces exactly what they're after.

Comment: ya, the fat arrow really can solve the issue if I want to bind ``this`` to the function, but what if I want to bind another object? Under this context, the fat arrow may not apply. But if ``(-> ...).bind`` can make effect, then I'd like to try this way. Thank you all :)